# Updating Pgadmin4 from 3.4 to 4.2

Tags: pgadmin-4

I have installed pgadmin4 and i can access it from browser.I have to update it from 3.4 version to 4.2,how to update it as there are docs only on installing pgadmin not on updating pgadmin.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should backup your databases and reinstall pgadmin